# Python Qt - Connect function to each button

Tags: python, qt

I am trying to build an hdri browser in Maya with python/Qt but I have limited knowledge on this subject. Basically I am trying to print the path of each "jpg" on a folder.

I built an UI with buttons as images and when I click on them I need them to print the respective path.

Ex: Button_01 > prints D:/Hdris/HDRI_01.jpg, Button_02 > prints D:/Hdris/HDRI_02.jpg, etc...

I understand that my code is a bit of a mess right now, that's why I can't connect the button press to the loop I have where I create the buttons. How can I organize this better?

Thank you.

```
from PySide2 import QtWidgets
from PySide2 import QtGui
from PySide2 import QtCore

from shiboken2 import wrapInstance

import maya.OpenMayaUI as omui

import glob, os

def maya_main_window():
    main_window_ptr = omui.MQtUtil.mainWindow()
    return wrapInstance( int(main_window_ptr), QtWidgets.QWidget )

class PicButton(QtWidgets.QAbstractButton):
    
    def __init__(self, pixmap,  parent=None ):
        
        super(PicButton, self).__init__(parent)
        self.pixmap = pixmap
        
        self.pressed.connect( self.press )
        

    def paintEvent(self, event):

        painter = QtGui.QPainter(self)
        
        painter.drawPixmap(event.rect(), self.pixmap)
        
        
        pix = painter.fillRect(  event.rect(), QtGui.QBrush( QtGui.QColor (150,150,150,128) )   )  if self.underMouse() else self.pixmap

    def enterEvent(self, event):
        self.update()
        
    def leaveEvent(self, event):
        self.update()
        
    def press(self):
        print('Button image Pressed! To do...')
                
    def sizeHint(self):
        return QtCore.QSize(200, 100)
        

class TestDialog(QtWidgets.QDialog):
    
    def __init__(self, parent=maya_main_window()):
        super(TestDialog, self).__init__(parent)

        self.setWindowTitle('Test Dialog')
        self.setMinimumWidth(200)     

        self.create_widgets()

    def create_widgets(self):
        
        main_layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)
        
        pathToHdris = "D:/CG_CONTENT/HDRIS/HDRI_BROWSER/"
        os.chdir(pathToHdris)
        

        for item, hdri in enumerate( glob.glob("*.jpg") ):
            
            

            newPath = pathToHdris+str(hdri)
            
            pixmap = QtGui.QPixmap(newPath)

            
            self.my_button = PicButton(pixmap)
            self.my_button.setCursor(QtGui.QCursor(QtCore.Qt.PointingHandCursor))
            self.my_button.setMaximumSize(200,100)
                                      
            
            main_layout.addWidget(self.my_button)
        
        
if __name__ == "__main__":

    try:
        test_dialog.close()
        test_dialog.deleteLater()
    except:
        pass

    test_dialog = TestDialog()
    test_dialog.show()
```

[image: dcc]

Comment: Just call `self.my_button.connect(self.my_button.press)` in a loop where you create it. Meanwhile it's not clear why you reassign `self.my_button` there. If you do not need all your created buttons then just use a local variable, otherwise you can store it in a list, for example

Comment: thanks for the reply @Alexey, but when I am getting an error "# TypeError: PySide2.QtCore.QObject.connect(): not enough arguments # " When I enter self.my_button.connect(self.my_button.press) in the loop.

Comment: `self.my_button.pressed.connect(self.my_button.press)`